# Table,View Or Sequence reference 'LN_GRAPH_PERC.DATE_RED' not allowed in this context

Tags: oracle, plsql

I can not change the `ln_graph_debt.date_red`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetContactFormalNames
AS
   aki     DATE := TRUNC (SYSDATE - 3);
   aki_1   DATE := TRUNC (ln_graph_debt.date_red);
BEGIN
   IF (aki_1 = aki)
   THEN
      DECLARE account_name_1 AS INT*/

      INSERT INTO TEL_LOAN_GRAPH (loan_id,
                                  TOTAL_COUNTED,
                                  DATE_RED,
                                  OBLIGATE_NUMBER,
                                  ACCOUNT_CODE,
                                  ACCOUNT_NAME)
         SELECT d.loan_id,
                CAST (d.summ_red AS NUMBER) + CAST (p.summ_red AS NUMBER)
                   AS Total_Counted,
                d.date_red,
                d.obligate_number,
                l.account_code,
                l.account_name
           FROM ln_graph_debt d, ln_graph_perc p, ln_account l
          WHERE     d.loan_id = p.loan_id
                AND d.loan_id = l.loan_id
                AND p.date_red = d.date_red;
   END IF;
END GetContactFormalNames;
```

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetContactFormalNames
AS
 aki DATE :=  TRUNC(SYSDATE - 3);
 aki_1 DATE :=  TRUNC(ln_graph_debt.date_red);

BEGIN
IF (
  aki_1 = aki 
) 
THEN

Comment: Could you post the error you are getting when you run the code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
aki_1   DATE := TRUNC (ln_graph_debt.date_red);
```

You can't reference a table that way; you'll have to `SELECT` into the variable, or write a function which will return a value.

```
select d.date_red
  into aki_1
  from ln_graph_debt d
  where ...
```

`WHERE` clause should contain a condition  so that `SELECT` returns only a single value; otherwise, you'll get the `TOO-MANY-ROWS` (or, perhaps, `NO-DATA-FOUND`).

---

Also, there's an obvious error, a superfluous `DECLARE` within the `IF`. You probably meant to comment it?

Comment: I did this one and there is not error, however the procedure is not working and not copying the selected into TEL_LOAN_GRAPH

Comment: If nothing is inserted into TEL_LOAN_GRAPH, then check WHERE clause - it is responsible for that.